# Returning only 0-9 and dashes from string

Tags: php, regex, string

I would like to take a string, and strip any characters apart from 0-9 and - (dashes).

**Example:**

if I have a string that looks like:

> 10-abc20-30

How can I make this string return

> 10-20-30

(Strip all characters besides numbers and dashes)

Is there some kind of regex to use within preg_match or str_replace ?

Answer (score 12):

```
$result = preg_replace('/[^\d-]+/', '', $subject);
```

`[^\d-]` matches any character except digits or dash; the `+` says "one or more" of those, so adjacent characters will be replaced at once.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data is in $string, this will remove all characters except for dashes and digits

```
$string = preg_replace('/[^-0-9]/', null, $string);
```